# Usage of BYTES in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I was wondering what might be a use case where someone would be using the `BYTES` type in BigQuery? In digging through the public datasets that are provided, the only place I could find the usage of the `BYTES` data type is in the `bitcoin_blockchain` dataset, and in that case it looks like the data could be base64-encoded as a string (briefly glancing at the preview it seems this may already be like this)?

So basically my question is what are some use-cases for using the Bytes datatype, where it couldn't just as easily be done using the String type. (Does anyone store multimedia data in BQ or a data warehouse?). Could BQ do everything it currently does without the BYTES type or is that an essential (and used) type?

Comment: I believe non-unicode strings would be better stored as `BYTES` instead of `STRING` to ensure compatibility.  This is likely made available to ensure legacy and less-typical systems can easily load to BQ without requiring transformations.  I doubt it is intended for binary blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

BASE64 string inflate the data by 33% on the size. Considering BigQuery charge you by the size of the data stored, and the size of data that is scanned, if there is lots of binary data to the degree that cost is a concern, BYTES gives you lower cost.

Comment: understood, but do you know of a use case where that is actually the case?

Comment: There should be many. One case that I know is, to achieve crypto-shredding (in a very small granularity), an encryption key table is needed. Since the key is generated by KEYS.NEW_KEYSET() which returns BYTES, and AEAD.DECRYPT_ functions accept keysets only in BYTES, there is just no point saving the key in STRING.